# Deriving the absorption coefficient

Tags: electromagnetism, harmonic-oscillator, absorption

Show that for a dilute medium and near resonance, the absorption coefficient is
$$\alpha(\omega)=\frac{Ne^2}{4m\epsilon_0c}\frac{\gamma}{(\omega_0-\omega)^2+(\gamma/2)^2}$$
From the Lorentz Oscillator Model, we have:
$$n^2(\omega)=1+\frac{Ne^2}{m_e\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2+i\gamma_j \omega}\right)$$
I'm not sure how to proceed. I know a dilute medium has $n\approx 1$ and near resonance means $\omega \approx \omega_0$, but I'm not sure how to apply these to find $\alpha(\omega)$.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I still don't understand how $\epsilon$ can lead us to $\alpha$.

Comment: Are you starting for some given model, like the drude model? Or what is your starting point?

Comment: @hft The Lorentz Oscillator Model, which models the electron as a simple harmonic oscillator. I am not using the drude model.

Comment: You need to calculate the complex optical constant $\epsilon$, where $\vec D = \epsilon \vec E$. You will have to see how the damping term enters, since that is not currently in your expression for $n^2$ ($n^2$ is the real part of $\epsilon$).

Comment: @hft Oh sure, I can easily add the damping term. I've done it just now.

Comment: Now I think you just take the imaginary part of $1/\epsilon$. Or maybe it is the imaginary part of $\epsilon$. I forget which is the definition of the absorption.

Comment: @hft We have $\epsilon = \epsilon_0 + \frac{P(t)}{E(t)}=\epsilon_0 + \frac{Ne^2}{m_e\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2+i\gamma_j \omega}\right)$

Comment: @hft How is absorption related to $\epsilon$?

Comment: In Gaussian CGS units the relationship is something like: $\alpha = \frac{4\pi \omega}{c}Im({\epsilon})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absorption coefficient is derived from the solution of the equation of motion for a forced damped oscillator (see for instance https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-osuniversityphysics/chapter/15-6-forced-oscillations/ or for a more involved derivation https://physics.byu.edu/faculty/colton/docs/phy442-resources/Lorentz-oscillator-model.pdf ).

If you assume additionally $|(\omega -\omega_0)| << \omega_0$ and $\gamma << \omega_0$ (which means you can approximately replace $\omega^2-\omega_0^2$ with $2\omega_0(\omega-\omega_0)$ and $\gamma^2\omega^2$ with $\gamma^2\omega_0^2$ ) and then use the fact that the time averaged power emitted by a charge $e$ oscillating with amplitude $A$ is

$$\frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{\omega^4 e^2 A^2}{3c^3}$$

you will get the expression for the absorption coefficient you quoted.

Comment: Thank you, but I had the impression that if I write the $n^2(\omega)$ as $n^2(\omega)=1+x$, where $x=\frac{Ne^2}{m_e\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2+i\gamma_j \omega}\right)$, and then expand $n(\omega)=\sqrt{1+x}$ as $1-\frac{1}{2}x$, then I could somehow link that with the absorption coefficient $\alpha(\omega)$?

Comment: @rb3652 You have to take the real part of the complex amplitude if you want to get to the expression you quoted (see https://physics.byu.edu/faculty/colton/docs/phy442-resources/Lorentz-oscillator-model.pdf ) and then additionally assume $|(\omega -\omega_0)| << \omega_0$ and $\gamma << \omega_0$ and then square the resulting amplitude to get the absorption coefficient as indicated above

Comment: I got it! Thank you.